# MySQL view - poor performance

Tags: mysql, database, view

I joined a few tables into a view for easier coding. Now when I join a few tables with that view, I get poor performance. While I'm getting more rows in view, the speed of those queries is dramatically decreased. I wrote a lot of code using this view so I don't like the solution to rewrite all of those queries :). Is there any elegant solution to speed up this view when I join it with other tables?

This is one of my queries where `tickets_parsed` is a view:

```
SELECT detailValue, SUM(total_tickets) AS total_tickets, SUM(money_in) AS money_in, SUM(handling_charges) AS handling_charges
FROM (
    SELECT bsid, COUNT(*) AS total_tickets, SUM(amount_total) AS money_in, SUM(handling_charges) AS handling_charges
    FROM `bingo`.tickets_parsed
    WHERE tickettime BETWEEN '$date' AND '$date2a'
    AND ticketstatus <> 'CLOSED'
    GROUP BY bsid
    ORDER BY NULL
) AS sub
NATURAL JOIN betshop_details
WHERE detailID = 5
GROUP BY detailValue
ORDER BY NULL
```

Comment: BTW, while I generally hate the practice of prefixing table names (e.g. 'tbl_users'), I think it's a really good idea to prefix views (e.g. v_tickets_parsed). This makes it really easy to spot the `views` in a list of `tables`.

Comment: Can you post the table declares for this, and also and EXPLAIN of the query (so we can see what indexes it is choosing to use). Note that natural joins can be a touch dangerous (ie, what happens in future if someone add a column called handling chargers to the table betshop_details).

Answer (score 0):

You query uses the view in a sub query, which likely prevents it using indexes. But I am not sure that the sub query is necessary.

You could possibly use something like this:-

```
SELECT a.detailValue, COUNT(*) AS total_tickets, SUM(b.amount_total) AS money_in, SUM(b.handling_charges) AS handling_charges
FROM bingo.tickets_parsed a
INNER JOIN betshop_details b
ON a.bsid = b.bsid
WHERE a.detailID = 5
AND b.tickettime BETWEEN '$date' AND '$date2a'
AND b.ticketstatus <> 'CLOSED'
GROUP BY a.detailValue
ORDER BY NULL
```